# Use users timezone across all SharePoint sites

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile, timezone

What I want to achieve is this:

we are using SharePoint 2013 and I want to set my timezone and have all SharePoint sites respect this. 
I am a bit confused because there are several places where one could set a timezone.

1. Site
   `https://<main url>/sites/<site>/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=User`
2. The Web-App (?)
   `https://<main url>/_layouts/15/regionalsetng.aspx?Type=User`
3. My Site 
      `https://<mysite url>/_layouts/15/EditProfile.aspx?UserSettingsProvider=<ID here>`

I changed the timezone on my site (3) in my profile but that does not have any effect on any SP site. I still see all dates/times in the timezone that has been configured for the site. When I try to change it on site or web level I get an error message whilst trying to save my changes to the profile there (this site has not been shared with you).

I found a good explanation of the problem that I have with a fixed timezone on a SP site for all visitors:

http://www.techmikael.com/2014/05/employees-in-multiple-time-zones-make.html

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from our admins. They had to do the following:

1. You need to set a proper timezone for the web application (Central Administration).
2. The application pool account of the publishing farm and farm account of consuming farm have to be set as administrators (full control) under permissions.

With these changes the timezone change on a users profile will be reflected on any site of the farm.